# No access to modern pages on Subsites depite correct permissions. Please help

Tags: permissions, modern-pages, web-partmodern-w

I am the Owner of a 2016 Site Collection with a complete set of multilevel subsites. On a 3rd level subsite I have a modern page with an excel viewer Webpart. Permissions are not inherited anymore, but "everyone except external users" has read permissions to this site. That works as intended for all the other sites and content, but not for this modern page. So people now start requesting access, which I wanted to avoid in the first place. Any idea?

What I have tried so far:
- Check and check and check again the permissions. All correct. The page and the Webpart do not have unique permissions.
- I have read somewhere, that "everyone except external users" would need same permission on site collection level as well to work. Did that, nothing changed.

Comment: Steamroller Approach: delete and redo. Now it´s working like intended.

Answer (score 1):

The Excel file which you are displaying in the web part is likely located in a SharePoint document library that has a more restricted permission set.  Locate the document library which holds your actual Excel file in your SharePoint site, and set the permissions of that library to also include "Everyone except external users".

Comment: The second level subsite has individual permissions and this site in questions inherit those permissions. I have checked it now again, the document library has no unique permission but inherits from the 3rd level site which inherits from the second level site. "Everyone except external users" has "view" permission everywhere.
And if the Excel file would be the culprit, then everyone should still see the site with an empty webpart, or am I wrong?